# How to use Transform to curve the child widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have ScaleWidget Like the below image:

[image]

How to curve the edges widget with Transform? I want to implement below one:

[image]

```
  Transform(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
    transform: Matrix4.identity(),
    child: ScaleWidget()
)
```

Comment: you cannot use `Transform` for that

Comment: @pskink What do you recommend?

Comment: something similar https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fd59d240beb8dd9d780f978e5c76b3c#file-sized_content_scrollable-dart-L250